# Java command prompt error (Extention mechanism no longer supported)

Tags: java, eclipse

After a long time I tried to run my Eclipse, I got:

> Failed to create java virtual machine

So I searched and tried changing some `eclipse.ini` lines to `-Xmx512m`.

I thought it was Eclipse problem, I tried command prompt but the `java` command returned:

> /lib/ext exists, extensions mechanism no longer supported; Use -classpath instead.
>   .Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I have jre1.9.0 (which I don't remember installing this version).

Comment: JRE 1.9 is not yet released and is probably incompatible with any current version of Eclipse.  I suggest you install Java 8 and make sure Eclipse uses it instead of 9.

Comment: so java automatically updated to jre 1.9? how do I disable that?

Comment: No, Java will NOT update to 1.9.  Somehow you (or somebody using your computer) managed to download and install Java 9.

Comment: if lib/ext directory is empty, just delete it.

Answer (score 3):

The extensions mechanism was removed in Java 9, much to my irritation. You could specify an extensions directory on -Djava.ext.dirs or extension jars could be put in $JAVA_HOME/lib/ext and all the jars would be loaded before loading your classpath, and even before a lot of standard libraries. The lords of Java decided that nobody was using this, but I beg to differ. [JDK9 release notes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-A78CC891-701D-4549-AA4E-B8DD90228B4B).

Comment: OK this is a very old question, but I needed an answer today.